# Finding proportions.......

Tags: calculus, propositional-calculus

kindly accept my apology in advance as i am not good in mathematics and this post might be trivial for some of the forum members. Consider I have $100 and I want to distribute among three poor people named: A, B, and C. These people has poverty index 1, 3, 4 respectively. (The scale of poverty index is from 1 to 10 where 1 means extreme poor and 10 means poor). Now i want to distribute 100 dollars in such way that person A (extreme poor guy) got significant portion of the money followed by B and then C. How can i come up with generic way of addressing this issue so that amount divide proportionally according to poverty index? Waiting for your positive and prompt reply.

Comment: This depends on how you define the poverty index.  Precisely, what does it mean to have a poverty index of "1" or "2" or "3"?  For example, "1" might mean 10% of average income, "2" might mean 20% of average income, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is one right answer to this question.  One possibility would be to distribute the money proportionally to $11-s$ where $s$ is the person's poverty score.  Then the money would be distributed proportionally $10:8:7$ with the poorest person getting the most (40 dollars), and the other two getting 32 and 28 dollars respectively.